# Can a transitive dependency be generated from a set of deterministic attributes?

Tags: relational-database

If we have a table that represents the entity "Students" and contains the following attributes:

**#StudentId | Name | Age | City | PostalCode | Neighborhood**

Being "StudentId" the primary key, we can analyze the dependencies between the attributes. If the combination of the attributes "City" and "PostalCode" allows us to determine the "Neighborhood", this could be considered a transitive dependency?

To better exemplify my doubt, I identify the transitive dependency as follows:

```
StudentId -> City
StudentId -> PostalCode
{City, PostalCode} -> Neighborhood
StudentId -> {City, PostalCode} -> Neighborhood
```

So, is it possible to have a transitive dependency from a set of attributes?

Answer (score -1):

As far as the formal definition of a transitive dependency is concerned, I have no idea.

But practically speaking, in MySQL the answer is effectively yes.  You can move neighborhood to another table, with city and postal code as a composite primary key (so long as you don't have neighborhoods where city or postal code is null).

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_dependency#Database_Management_Systems definition. So yes this example meets the formal definition. Depending on which country's `PostalCode` we're talking about, that might not exactly determine the `Neighbourhood`.

Comment: @AntC I think you are missing the point of the question; postal code alone does *not* determine neighborhood, it's the combination of postal code & city.  I don't see that wiki link addressing that.

Comment: At that link "A transitive dependency is a functional dependency ..."; all FDs allow for combinations of fields as determiners. In my city (in New Zealand) there's 5 Postcodes, each designating upwards of a dozen suburbs. That's why my caveat.